# Sorting nested Objects inside each other

Tags: javascript

I am having a hard time about inner sorting of nested objects. For example I have nested array object like below.

```
[
  {
    "project_id": "1155091124014397",
    "completed": [
       {
          "task_due_date": "2020-06-01",      
       },
       {
          "task_due_date": "2020-20-01",      
       },
       {
          "task_due_date": "2020-02-01",      
       },
    ],
  },
  {
    "project_id": "1155091124012597",
    "completed": [
       {
          "task_due_date": "2020-22-01",      
       },
       {
          "task_due_date": "2020-05-01",      
       },
       {
          "task_due_date": "2020-01-01",      
       },
    ],
  },
]
```

So I am trying to sort each completed nested Array Object inside. But not to sure how to handle this. And tried something like below.

```
let sorted = array.map(element => {
   let nested = _.orderBy(element.completed, 'task_due_date');
   return nested
});

return sorted
```

But not worked out.

expected results is

```
[
  {
    "project_id": "1155091124014397",
    "completed": [
       {
          "task_due_date": "2020-02-01",      
       },
       {
          "task_due_date": "2020-06-01",      
       },
       {
          "task_due_date": "2020-20-01",      
       },
    ],
  },
  {
    "project_id": "1155091124012597",
    "completed": [
       {
          "task_due_date": "2020-01-01",      
       },
       {
          "task_due_date": "2020-05-01",      
       },
       {
          "task_due_date": "2020-22-01",      
       },
    ],
  },
]
```

Dates are sorted.

Comment: Solution depends on what expected results structure is

Comment: I added the sorted expected results @charlietfl

Comment: Change approach then and use a loop (for loop, foreach etc) and sort the `completed` property array in place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to convert your date strings to date objects, and then you can sort based on those objects:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "project_id": "1155091124014397",
    "completed": [
       {
          "task_due_date": "2020-06-01",      
       },
       {
          "task_due_date": "2020-20-01",      
       },
       {
          "task_due_date": "2020-02-01",      
       },
    ],
  },
  {
    "project_id": "1155091124012597",
    "completed": [
       {
          "task_due_date": "2020-22-01",      
       },
       {
          "task_due_date": "2020-05-01",      
       },
       {
          "task_due_date": "2020-01-01",      
       },
    ],
  },
];

const toDate = dateStr => {
  const components = dateStr.split('-');
  const [year, date, month] = components;
  return new Date(`${year}-${month}-${date}`);
};

const sortByDate = (a, b) => {
  const aDate = toDate(a['task_due_date']);
  const bDate = toDate(b['task_due_date']);
  return aDate - bDate;
};

arr.forEach(el => {
  el.completed.sort(sortByDate);
});
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: @Tay no problem

Answer (score 0):

```
Date.prototype.formatdate=date=>{const compo=date.split('-'); return new Date(compo[0],compo[2],compo[1])}
      const sorttime = (a,b) => {
          date=new Date()
          const  x=date.formatdate(a.task_due_date)
         const  y=date.formatdate(b.task_due_date)
        return x-y}

      arr.filter(({...rest})=>({completed:rest.completed.sort(sorttime)}))
```